# Google Script onChange 3rd Party INSERT_ROW

Tags: javascript, logging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

I've been trying to find a definite answer to this for over a year now. Hopefully one of you will have a solution.

I need a simple script to fire when a new row is added. That's it. The only problem that myself and everyone that has tried to help me is facing is it is from a 3rd party source (form).

The 3rd party source ADDS A NEW ROW TO THE SHEET UPON SUBMISSION but the trigger won't fire! Why? Right now I'm running a simple log test to see if it updates on edit and/or on change and so far it's a no to both. Can someone explain why this is? I've searched the entire internet to find a solution and haven't found one.

The 3rd party form is through Formstack and there is no reason it shouldn't trigger within Sheets because a new row is being added!

Below is the simple function I'm using to see if it triggers on edit or on change:

```
function onChange(e){
 Logger.log("onChange event fired");
}

function onEdit(e){
 Logger.log("onEdit event fired");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever got the answer to this, but the onChange() is an installed trigger. You have to add it in like this:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onChange")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
```

where `ss` is the handle to the active spreadsheet.

Comment: Any way to trigger it based on the `onChange()` event? For example when `e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW"`? I've got a conditional at the top of my script to `return;` if it's not an inserted row, but it would be nice to avoid calling the script entirely.